# Why are the polygons in my GML not rendered?

Tags: qgis, gml

I tried to view GML files from download services ( http://services.cuzk.cz/gml/inspire/cp/epsg-5514/ ) and I have a problem with viewing of polygons from layer "CP:CadastralParcel". This Layer contains reference point and polygon of parcel, but I see only reference point.

Boundaries from layer "CP:CadastralBoundary" I see fine.

Could you help me?
Thanks

Comment: which viewer do you use

Comment: I use Quantum GIS 1.8.0 on Windows 7 Professional, 64 bit. I use function Add vector layer.

Answer (score 6):

Same reason --> OGR does not support multiple geometries in one feature
http://www.weichand.de/2012/08/26/qgis-wfs-2-0-plugin-update/comment-page-1/#comment-8177

~~ UPDATE ~~

After the first import of your GML-file there will be a .gfs file in the same directory. This file contains the following part:

```
<Name>CadastralParcel</Name>
<ElementPath>CadastralParcel</ElementPath>
<GeometryType>1</GeometryType>
```

Change it to:

```
<Name>CadastralParcel</Name>
<ElementPath>CadastralParcel</ElementPath>
<GeometryType>3</GeometryType>
<GeometryElementPath>geometry</GeometryElementPath>
```

After reopening your GML-file the CadastralParcels polygons will be displayed instead of the reference points.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried this solution and it works great.

Comment: It should be fixed in the next GDAL version according to this changeset: http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/changeset/25183, see http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/4897

Answer (score 0):

With QGIS 3.22 (probably since quite some time) you can now drag and drop the XML file to QGIS and it will detect the different layers

[image]