# Rendering GML in QGIS 1.9.0

Tags: qgis, gml

I have a set of GML geometries (see [here](http://services.cuzk.cz/wfs/inspire-cp-wfs.asp?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&srsname=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::5514&bbox=-551748,-1124214,-550000,-1124000&version=2.0.0&typename=CadastralParcel)), which I try to load in QGIS. The set contains both points and polygons, but when loaded into QGIS, only points are shown. I tried to follow [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37217/why-are-the-polygons-in-my-gml-not-rendered/41029), but the piece of code suggested for overriding is not present in .gfs file. Any chance to make it work?

I tried using OGR2OGR for converting to .shp, but only the points are converted.

Comment: Please post how you tried to manipulate the .gfs.

Comment: I tried to change `<Name>CadastralParcel</Name>
<ElementPath>CadastralParcel</ElementPath>
<GeometryType>1</GeometryType>` as suggested by Juergen Weichand at [this thread](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37217/why-are-the-polygons-in-my-gml-not-rendered/41029).The problem is there is no such part of the code in the file :-)

Comment: You have to save the file to your hard disk, for example insprire.gml. After loading that into qgis, you get another file inspire.gfs next to it. You have to manipulate that file as discribed in the previous thread. Then close Qgis, reopen it, and load the gml again.

Comment: I can't edit the file as supposed in that thread because there is **no such code** to change. If I just add Juergen's code to .gfs file, nothing happens.

Comment: Please use Lisboa. The dev version 1.9 is undergoing severe changes in the process of getting to the 2.0 release. Plugins and other tools can suddenly stop working.

Comment: I'd like to, but I had some issues with running GRASS and was missing EPSG:5514 as well (needed for WMS in my country).

Comment: It should be fixed in the next GDAL version according to this changeset: http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/changeset/25183, see http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/4897

Answer (score 1):

Quantum GIS Lisboa creates the following **.gfs** file:

```
<GMLFeatureClassList>
  <GMLFeatureClass>
    <Name>CadastralParcel</Name>
    <ElementPath>CadastralParcel</ElementPath>
    <GeometryType>1</GeometryType>
    <SRSName>urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::5514</SRSName>
    <DatasetSpecificInfo>
      <FeatureCount>67</FeatureCount>
      <ExtentXMin>-551828.69000</ExtentXMin>
      <ExtentXMax>-549922.10000</ExtentXMax>
      <ExtentYMin>-1124381.29000</ExtentYMin>
      <ExtentYMax>-1123937.92000</ExtentYMax>
    </DatasetSpecificInfo>
    <PropertyDefn>
      <Name>areaValue</Name>
      <ElementPath>areaValue</ElementPath>
      <Type>Integer</Type>
    </PropertyDefn>
    <PropertyDefn>
      <Name>areaValue_uom</Name>
      <ElementPath>areaValue_uom</ElementPath>
      <Type>String</Type>
      <Width>2</Width>
    </PropertyDefn>
    <PropertyDefn>
      <Name>beginLifespanVersion</Name>
      <ElementPath>beginLifespanVersion</ElementPath>
      <Type>String</Type>
      <Width>20</Width>
    </PropertyDefn>
    <PropertyDefn>
      <Name>localId</Name>
      <ElementPath>inspireId|Identifier|localId</ElementPath>
      <Type>String</Type>
      <Width>14</Width>
    </PropertyDefn>
    <PropertyDefn>
      <Name>namespace</Name>
      <ElementPath>inspireId|Identifier|namespace</ElementPath>
      <Type>String</Type>
      <Width>10</Width>
    </PropertyDefn>
    <PropertyDefn>
      <Name>label</Name>
      <ElementPath>label</ElementPath>
      <Type>String</Type>
      <Width>7</Width>
    </PropertyDefn>
    <PropertyDefn>
      <Name>nationalCadastralReference</Name>
      <ElementPath>nationalCadastralReference</ElementPath>
      <Type>String</Type>
      <Width>14</Width>
    </PropertyDefn>
  </GMLFeatureClass>
</GMLFeatureClassList>
```

Lines 3 to 5 have to be changed.

Comment: Sadly v1.9.0 (alpha) generates this .gfs
`<GMLFeatureClassList>
  <GMLFeatureClass>
    <Name>CadastralParcel</Name>
    <ElementPath>CadastralParcel</ElementPath>
    <DatasetSpecificInfo>
      <FeatureCount>67</FeatureCount>` etc.
That's why I can't change GeometryType - there **is not any**.

Comment: strange, on Windows OSGEo4W 1.9.0 (3b88637) I get the same as from Lisboa. Please install Lisboa on your system and try again. After creating and changing the .gfs, you might work on with Qgis Master. Or take my example above, and save it locally as .gfs.

Comment: Do you know any other open source that would be capable of loading this GML?

Comment: GvSig is able to load gml data, but I did not get your file running. I'm not very familiar with that software anyway.

Comment: I didn't succeed with gvSIG nor uDig. But it's working fine with QGIS Lisboa. Hope it'll be fixed in 1.9.x/2.0.