# Import .gfs file into PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, ogr2ogr

Is it possible to import a .gfs file into PostGIS?

I can open the .gfs file in QGis, so I assume it is a geographic file of some kind: but I'm not sure how to get it into PostGIS.

I have Googled but can't find any examples of doing this with ogr2ogr. Do I need to convert it into some intermediate format first?

Comment: Have you seen the first example for [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html)?

Comment: @Mike T, gfs is not any file format that is supported by GDAL. It is a schema file that GDAL creates after resolving the schema of GML data. Therefore the first link to read is http://www.gdal.org/drv_gml.html. Before using ogr2ogr at least I must also read every time the PostGIS driver page because the complete connection string is too hard to remember http://www.gdal.org/drv_pg.html.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41065/rendering-gml-in-qgis-1-9-0. It appears to be a file QGIS creates after reading GML. Following on from user30184's useful comment, it is a schema file created after parsing GML, if there is no XSD present.

Comment: It could be worthwhile seeing how OGR uses this file [in the unit testing](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/trunk/autotest/ogr/ogr_gml_read.py). From this, it seems that most .gfs files have a .gml file that should be read by OGR. Do you have corresponding .gml files?